# Creating first gem, depends on activerecord, should my tests hit the db?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I'm creating a gem, and my class initialize method takes an ActiveRecord model as a parameter.

This isn't a rails related gem.

In my unit tests (rspec), how should I create a unit test that connects to mysql?

I find it odd that I have to create a database.yml file, and then put my credentials etc. for a unit test.

Should I be using sqlite instead?

If someone can provide an example of how I should do this that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll need an ActiveRecord object, even relaying that your received object inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.

Instead, what IMO would be better is to use a mocked ActiveRecord::Base object. By using a mocked object, instead of your required original one, you can simulate any behavior and state of your active_record object and your tests will not require database connections, which will allow them to run incredible faster.

You can read a little bit more about mocking (theory) here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Practice (with rspec) here:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames

Hope it helps!